# Can I use AES128/ECB/PKCS7 encryption with Java 1.4

Tags: encryption, aes, pkcs#7, java1.4, ecb

I have a string holding some parameters that needs to be encrypted in AES-128 in ECB mode with PKCS7 padding, and then Base-64 encoded.

My code base is Java 1.4. Is this possible with Java 1.4 api ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100433/to-use-aes-with-256-bits-in-inbuild-java-1-4-api

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You would need a separate library for the base 64 encoding/decoding though. For the encryption you can use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")`. Note that PKCS#5 padding [is the same as PKCS#7 padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172).

Comment: Note that you shouldn't try and program security related applications on a runtime that doesn't receive security updates anymore. Try and see if you can get it compiling / running on Java 1.8 instead; Java RE is highly backwards compatible (although it *is* possible to break compatibility of course).